# How to store an input from a user into a specified index in an array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Im having trouble with homework assignment, i need to ask a user for a number and location and then store that number into the specific location in the list. my python skills are pretty basic but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Question:

Two players take turns inserting a number in the range of 0 through 9 into the array at any empty location. Each player can choose any remaining number, but each number can only be used once.

example of what is supposed to happen:

player 1:  you're number? 7

position to be entered? 9

position: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
     | | | | | | | | |7| |
```

my failed attempt:

```
data = []

x = raw_input('integer: ')

for i in range(10):

    data.insert(9, x)


print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` returns a string and not an integer in python. To convert it to an integer, you need to do `x = int(raw_input('integer: '))`.

Then your insert function should work fine, but be aware that you're just adding the same integer into every slot.

First make a list with empty values:

```
data = [' ']*10
```

Then just do `data[9-1] = str(x)`. No `list.insert` is needed :), nor are any loops.

Remember that indexing starts at 0, so what you mean by 9th position python thinks as 8th.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [None]*10
data[9] = x
```

should work you need to give it enough slots

the problem with your code is here

```
for i in range(10):

    data.insert(9, x)
```

you are inserting a new item at position 9 ... however your array is empty so there is no position 9 to insert at

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data=[-1]*10 #initialize data to length 10 with invalid values for input
x = -1
while not (0<=x<=9):
    try:
        x=raw_input("integer : ")
    except ValueError:
        print("enter an integer")
data[9] = x
```

You can expand this, the main thing is converting to integers and catching input error.

Answer (score 0):

my successful attempt:

```
data = ['']*10

x = raw_input('integer: ')
position_to_be_entered=9
data[position_to_be_entered-1]=int(x)


print data
```